# How to explain this code in resolveGetterConflicts() method in mybatis? why boolean is different from other class?

Tags: java, overriding, mybatis

```
private void resolveGetterConflicts(Map<String, List<Method>> conflictingGetters) {
for (Entry<String, List<Method>> entry : conflictingGetters.entrySet()) {
  Method winner = null;
  String propName = entry.getKey();
  for (Method candidate : entry.getValue()) {
    if (winner == null) {
      winner = candidate;
      continue;
    }
    Class<?> winnerType = winner.getReturnType();
    Class<?> candidateType = candidate.getReturnType();
    if (candidateType.equals(winnerType)) {
      if (!boolean.class.equals(candidateType)) {
        throw new ReflectionException(
            "Illegal overloaded getter method with ambiguous type for property "
                + propName + " in class " + winner.getDeclaringClass()
                + ". This breaks the JavaBeans specification and can cause unpredictable results.");
      } else if (candidate.getName().startsWith("is")) {
        winner = candidate;
      }
    } else if (candidateType.isAssignableFrom(winnerType)) {
      // OK getter type is descendant
    } else if (winnerType.isAssignableFrom(candidateType)) {
      winner = candidate;
    } else {
      throw new ReflectionException(
          "Illegal overloaded getter method with ambiguous type for property "
              + propName + " in class " + winner.getDeclaringClass()
              + ". This breaks the JavaBeans specification and can cause unpredictable results.");
    }
  }
  addGetMethod(propName, winner);
}
}
```

In my opinion, an overriding method in subclass maybe return a subtype of the type returned by the overridden method in superclass, obove method can resolve this case.

But, i am very confused with these code in the method:

```
      if (!boolean.class.equals(candidateType)) {
        throw new ReflectionException(
            "Illegal overloaded getter method with ambiguous type for property "
                + propName + " in class " + winner.getDeclaringClass()
                + ". This breaks the JavaBeans specification and can cause unpredictable results.");
      } else if (candidate.getName().startsWith("is")) {
        winner = candidate;
      }
```

```

Why boolean is different from other class?Can someone can help me? thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, because JavaBean Spec allows follow:

```
public boolean isBool() {return true;}
public boolean getBool() {return false;}
```